# Воспроизвести исходный массив

Tags: php

Есть такой цикл по массиву:

```
<? foreach ($notificationsItem['posts'] as $value): ?>
    <?= $value->LogUrl ?>
<? endif;?>
```

Как воспроизвести исходный массив(создать) по выводу? Иначе создать массив, который бы прокручивался в этом цикле c одним полем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($notificationsItem['posts'] as $value){
    echo $value->LogUrl;
    $newArr[] = $value->LogUrl;
}
```

Так? Чет с трудом понимаю что вы хотите получить в итоге. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.